# Using GROUP_CONCAT in linq

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, group-concat

I am using ASP.NET and MYSQL for an application, but unable to use group_concat with LINQ. Need help !! Here is Query in MYSQL

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( table1.name ) , table2.number 
FROM  tabele1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.number = table1.number
WHERE table2.class =  "A"
GROUP BY table2.number
```